# how can I create recursion with all previous lines in t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Initial data: there are conditionally 100 people who eat nuts, sweets, apples ... in total, the maximum amount of apples, sweets, nuts, 1000 pieces for all. These people eat 2 meals a day and each eats a different amount of sweets, apples and nuts. How many nuts, sweets, apples they ate for the first time is known.
We need to calculate how much they can eat in the second meal, if each person can eat up to 10 sweets, apples and nuts per day.
They take turns eating and I need to calculate how much each of them can still eat these sweets, apples and nuts today. Thus, I need to calculate how much of everything is left from the original 1000 pieces of nuts, sweets, apples after each person. And how much more each of these people can eat nuts, sweets, apples, taking into account the last meal and taking into account that they can eat up to 10 pieces of nuts, sweets, apples per day
I think this should be solved by recursion and in each iteration use the previous records and the current record. Or can you offer me some other way to solve it?
My wrong desicion
There is a table:

```
select 1 num, 1 s,  50 ss, 11 b, 20 bs
    union
    select 2 num, 1 s, 101 ss, 11 b, 50 bs
    union
    select 3 num, 2 s, 103 ss, 12 b, 50 bs
```

I need to recursively connect each of these lines sequentially in each iteration by num with myself and with the previous lines.

```
1 iteration:
[n  num s   ss  b   bs  num_    s_  ss_ b_  bs_
1   1   1   50  11  20  1   1   50  11  20][1]
2 iteration:
[n  num s   ss  b   bs  num_    s_  ss_ b_  bs_
2   2   1   101 11  50  2   1   50  11  20
2   2   1   101 11  50  2   1   101 11  50][2]
3 iteration:
[n  num s   ss  b   bs  num_    s_  ss_ b_  bs_
3   3   2   103 12  50  3   1   50  11  20
3   3   2   103 12  50  3   1   101 11  50
3   3   2   103 12  50  3   2   103 12  50][3]
Total:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx0Jv.png)

At each iteration, I will do some more calculations, so I'm looking for a way to output just such a recursion with one computational part.
Below is my attempt, but it fails to add the current anchor part to the iteration:

```
    with a as  
(
    select 1 num, 1 s,  50 ss, 11 b, 20 bs
    union
    select 2 num, 1 s, 101 ss, 11 b, 50 bs
    union
    select 3 num, 2 s, 103 ss, 12 b, 50 bs

)
--select * from res

,
rec as (
select 1 n, a.num, a.s, a.ss, a.b, a.bs, a.num num_, a.s s_, a.ss ss_, a.b b_, a.bs bs_  from a where num =1
union all
 
select n+1, a.num, a.s, a.ss, a.b, a.bs, rec.num num_ , rec.s s_, rec.ss ss_, rec.b b_, rec.bs bs_ from rec,a 
where a.num=rec.num+1-- and a.num<>rec.num_



)
select  top 20 * from rec order by n,num, num_
```

Comment: what exactly do you need?

Comment: I wrote the full condition in the topic itself - I hope it became clearer and maybe you will offer some other way to solve it in t-sql

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand what your need. You mention recursion, iterations, and calculations, but I see such things nowhere. The result set you indicate can be had with this simple self-join:

```
with a as  
(
    select 1 num, 1 s,  50 ss, 11 b, 20 bs
    union
    select 2 num, 1 s, 101 ss, 11 b, 50 bs
    union
    select 3 num, 2 s, 103 ss, 12 b, 50 bs

)
select * 
from 
    a
    inner join a a_prev on a_prev.num<=a.num
order by a.num,a_prev.num
```

Comment: May by you are right and i will think very much about your answer. But I need to calculate how many apples, candy and nut  was left after every people. And I don`t know exactly Can I use cumulative totals in this case... I will be think. Thanks a lot.